# To get files added today

Tags: python, glob

In a Folder i have 80000 + Files,Which every file name containing YYYYMMDD ,
i can use glob function to get the files by YYYYMMDD Pattern.

```
Current_Day = str((datetime.date.today().strftime("%Y%m%d")))
Directory = SourceFolder+'\*'+Current_Day+'*.PSV'
ListOfFiles = glob.glob(Directory)
```

I'm able to get list of files by using glob, Is there any advanced(Fast) way to get the files by using c_time or m_time ? Evec Creation time and Modified time will be of Current_Day

Answer (score 1):

You can use [os.stat](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.stat) and/or [os.lstat](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.stat) to retrieve file attributes:

```
import os
for file in os.listdir(SourceFolder):
    f_attr = os.stat(file)
    if datetime.fromtimestamp(f_attr.st_mtime) == date.today():
        print('Good file! %s' % file)
    else:
        print('Bad file! %s' % file)
```

Comment: Again it Goes into For Loop and check for the Modified time which ultimately take lot time

Comment: @Shiv There is no possible way of doing what you want without iterating through the folder contents...(none that I know of at least)

Comment: If you are working with Python >= 3.5 you can use [`os.scandir()`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0471/) it's a generator that yields a `DirEntry` object. You have to iterate over the directory one way or another...

Comment: Yes even i felt the same, without iteration its not possible as per my knowledge